# Labels Background - one per letter and not one per label when using curved placement in QGIS 3.20.3

Tags: qgis, labeling, background

When using Background on labels I expect it to show one homogeneous background, but instead I get one background per letter. It only occurs when I use "Curved" placement for the label.

Is there a way to solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: Increasing the x size of the background will get you overlapping individual background, it wont look really good but it will look continuous...

Comment: Workaround : instead of background, choose a buffer around letters and set a great value, it will look round but even curved, it will be filled between letters.

Answer (score 3):

This effect occurs a lot when using the `buffer size type`, as each letter doesn't use the same space. You can try to use the `fixed size type` instead, with an adequate x-y sizing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be changing the color to white:

[image]

Comment: Do you mean : changing text color to white, and no background color ? If so, this does not answer your question, which was about labels background set per letter